# StackOverFlow Error on line of code

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I am taking a programming class and set up code about computing a paycheck.  Everything works fine except for line 11.  I end up getting a stackoverflow error.

However when I remove this line of code

```
double weeksWages = pay(50, 10); // weeksWages is 550
```

The error goes away, but when running program, I end up with 10 instead of 550 that is intended.  This is probably really simple to fix, but not sure.  Thanks!

Here is the full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ComputePayCheck {    

  static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


  public static double pay(int hours, double hourlyRate) {
     int otHours = (hours > 40) ? hours - 40 : 0;
     double weeksWages = pay(50, 10); // weeksWages is 550
     return otHours;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
     int hours = in.nextInt();
     out.print("Enter hourly rate: ");
     double hourlyRate = in.nextDouble();
     out.print("Week's Salary is: " + pay(hours, hourlyRate));


  }

}
```

Comment: The line `double weeksWages = pay(50, 10); // weeksWages is 550` has no effect, other than generating the stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a stack overflow because your `pay` function is recursively calling itself with no end in sight. I'm not sure what the exact expected behaviour of your method is, but try something like this instead.

```
public static double pay(int hours, double hourlyRate) {
 int otHours = (hours > 40) ? hours - 40 : 0;
 return hourlyRate * otHours;
}
```

Comment: So far so good, the code is runnable.  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Glad this has worked out for you! If this has solved the problem could you go ahead and mark this answer as such? :)

Comment: It kind of solved my problem, but I'll mark it anyway. ;)